# How to place the subscript under two summation signs in a fraction?

Tags: math-mode, equations, subscripts

I would like to place a subscript under two summation signs in a fraction, in an equation. The code showed works when it is not in a fraction, but as soon as I use it in a fraction the subscript is placed after the two summation signs, instead of under the two summation signs.

```
\begin{equation} \frac{{\sum\sum\limits}_{i \neq j}
    \sum\limits_{x}\sum\limits_{y}[\pi_{x(i),y(j)} -
    \pi_{x(i)}\pi_{y(j)}]} {\sigma^2_X} 
\end{equation}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 10):

You need to enclose the two summation symbols in `\mathop{}` and then place `\limits` after that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \frac{\mathop{\sum\sum}\limits_{i \neq j}
    \sum\limits_{x}\sum\limits_{y}[\pi_{x(i),y(j)} -
    \pi_{x(i)}\pi_{y(j)}]}{\sigma^2_X} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: +1. Also, I'd add the new operator *double sum* `\DeclareMathOperator*{\dsum}{\sum\sum}`

Comment: @Sigur True, even thought I would only declare a new operator if I were to use this construct multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

If you use lualatex, you can place the `\limits` outside of the braces:

```
{\sum\sum}\limits_{i\neq j}
```

However, this will throw an error if compiled with pdflatex or xelatex, then you need a `\mathop`:

```
\mathop{\sum\sum}\limits_{i\neq j}
```

If you need this more often, you can define a new mathoperator (needs `amsmath`), if you use the starred Version, the default is the use of `\limits`.

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\ssum}{\sum\sum}
```

If you are inside a `\frac`, displaymode is turned of, you can switch it back on:

```
\begin{equation}
  \frac{\displaystyle \ssum_{i\neq j}}{2}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: It does not work. *Limit controls must follow a math operator. ...} {\sum\sum}\limits*

Comment: This won't work. `! Limit controls must follow a math operator.` Please improve your answer.

Comment: i compiled it! With lualatex using `mathtools` and `unicode-math`

Comment: @MaxNoe, in that case, it works.

Comment: @MaxNoe Aha! You found another `tex` vs. `luatex` incompatibility.

Comment: indeed, the key is lualatex. pdflatex throws the error, lualatex not.

Comment: This would appear to be a bug in LuaTeX, version 0.79.1 (distributed with TeXLive2014). It's no longer present in versions 0.79.2 and 0.79.3.x.